# Maximum limit of nping --rate option

Tags: network, penetration-test

[nping](https://nmap.org/nping/) - Network packet generation tool or ping utility.

There is an option called `--rate` which send probes at a given rate. What is the maximum rate that can be sent? or What is the limitation of the rate?

Comment: typically the rate of sending is limited to the network, not the local machine - there would be no theoretical limit as to how fast the local machine would generate packets to send to the wire - it's the wire that would impose the limit

Comment: Max rate is 1000 pps. Anything above 1000 is considered to be infinity.

Comment: can you point to a source where this is defined?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/ef8213a36c2e89233c806753a57b5cd473605408/nping/ArgParser.cc), it appears that while the software requires only that the rate be a positive integer, the rate is functionally capped at 1001 since the rate is also used to calculate a delay:

```
1000 / rate
```

Your actual maximum rate will depend on your machine resources and the network.

[A note in the code](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/bd67aa367261994e9f531ecd5af74ee5bcfa30ee/todo/nping.txt) also suggests that `1000` is a "very high rate" and is used as an extreme test case.